# Convert Latitude/Longitude to Web Mercator Pixels using PHP

Tags: php, geolocation, mercator

I'm trying to convert WGS 84 coordinates into pixels using web mercator projection. I want to print the position on a given map. I came across a PHP function which works fine if the map is an image of the whole world. I've been trying hard to extend this function so it also works if the map is just a clip (e.g. North America). I already found a solution for calculating the width but I failed to adjust the height calculation. How do I have to change the function?

(`$top` is the top left corner of the map image `[Array]`, `$bottom` the bottom right corner / `$this->width` is map width, `$this->height` is map height)

```
function cor($lat = null, $lon = null, $top, $bottom) {
    // Width
    $width = ($lon-$bottom[1]) * $this->width/($top[1]-$bottom[1]);
    // Height
    $latrad = ($lat * M_PI) / 180;
    $mercN = log(tan((M_PI / 4) + ($latrad / 2)));
    $height = (($this->height / 2) - ($this->width * $mercN / (2 * M_PI)));

    return Array($width, $height);
}
```

Thanks very much in advance! :)